# Writing entire queries in individual stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an application developed in .NET and the queries through stored procedures in SQL Server 2008, .NET Framework 4.0.

In stored procedures I have two sets :

1. each stored procedure contains only one query from a table
2. a stored procedure has entire queries related to that table

Example :

```
IF @Type = 'Select'
   'query'

IF @Type = 'Search'
   ''query
```

As I have developed the application and using both sets, I'm confused as to whether writing entire queries for a table (set 2) is a good practise?

Do that have any advantage or is it a bad coding practise to follow (ie. writing multiple queries in individual stored procedures)

Please suggest me options to follow.

Thank you

Comment: One word to research: **Single Responsibility Principle** - any software "thing" should do **one thing and one thing only** - therefore, you're "one stored procedure for every possible query on a table" is definitely a **horribly bad way** to do things - don't do this! This will become a **maintenance NIGHTMARE** of epic proportions in no time at all - **DON'T DO IT!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep all the queries (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and SELECT) related to a certain table in a single stored procedure, I can think of several problems with this approach:

First, security. Granting someone EXEC to the procedure, you might be granting him unnecessary rights.

Second, compile time increases with more code inside.

Third, more parameters defined and sent over the network.

Fourth, the output of the procedure is not clearly defined.

Fifth, servicing.

Sixth, don't do it :)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess some will disagree with me, but in my opintion it is bad practice. It's always better to write short, self explanatory code devided into a large number of functions (or stored procedures in this case) then to write a long code that have a lot of parts that doesn't actually belong together.

Always think about how to make the life easy for the poor bastard that will have to work with the code you are writing 18 monthes from now, since there is a good possiblility that you will be that poor bastard.